# Supporting multi-window in only tablets

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

I have an android app wherein I want to support multi-window only on tablets and not on phone. How do I achieve this ?

What I have read so far : `android:resizeableActivity` is the attribute which decides whether the app as a whole supports multi-window or not.

So what I want is more like a runtime check to disable multi-window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37402060/115145